# How can I change a color of a surface in VineCopula::plot.BiCop function?

Tags: r

Do you know how I can change a color of a surface in VineCopula::plot.BiCop function? I've tried to use a col argument but it's worked just for color of lines of a grid.

```r
library(VineCopula)
par.gauss<-BiCopTau2Par(1, .7, check.taus = TRUE)
obj.gauss <- BiCop(family = 1, par = par.gauss)
plot(obj.gauss,zlim=c(0,12))
```

I've tried:

```r
plot(obj.gauss,zlim=c(0,12), col="green")
```

but it's changed just a color of lines.

Comment: Please share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```r
n <- 70
plot(obj.gauss, zlim=c(0,12), col.regions=rainbow(n))
```

`n` gives the number of colors used in your plot. `rainbow` is a color palette, there are several others. Look at `?rainbow`, you could use

```r
hcl.colors(n)
rainbow(n)
heat.colors(n)
terrain.colors(n)
topo.colors(n)
cm.colors(n)
```

and there are several parameters, so for example

```r
plot(obj.gauss, zlim=c(0,12), col.regions=rainbow(120, s=0.5, alpha=0.75))
```